# Preencher campos com dados da base de dados após selecionar uma opção no <SELECT>

Tags: javascript, php, html5, ajax, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando desenvolver uma funcionalidade em que, ao escolher um operador em um formulário, as horas associadas a esse operador (hora de início e hora de fim) sejam automaticamente preenchidas nos campos correspondentes do formulário. O objetivo é garantir que, ao selecionar um operador, as informações de hora associadas a esse operador sejam exibidas instantaneamente nos campos apropriados do formulário.

Ao selecionar um operador, o JavaScript deveria capturar as horas associadas a esse operador e preencher automaticamente os campos de hora. No entanto, mesmo após várias tentativas e verificações, essa funcionalidade não está ocorrendo conforme o esperado.

````
<?php   $query_operadores = "SELECT nome_operador,id_matricula_operador,hora_inicio_turno, hora_fim_turno FROM tb_operadores, tb_turnos where tb_turnos.id_turno=tb_operadores.id_turno_operador_fk ORDER BY id_matricula_operador ASC";
        $resultado_operadores = $conn->query($query_operadores);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cadastro de Produção</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 50px auto;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 30px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        input[type="text"], input[type="number"], select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        input[type="date"], input[type="number"],input[type="time"], select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        button {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Cadastro de Produção</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="data_producao">Data:</label>
                <input type="date" id="data_producao" name="data_producao" value="today()">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="operador_producao">Operador:</label>
                <select id="operador_producao" name="operador_producao">
                <?php
                    while ($row_operador = $resultado_operadores->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $nome_operador = $row_operador['nome_operador'];
                        $id_operador = $row_operador['id_matricula_operador'];
                        $hora_inicio = $row_operador['hora_inicio_turno'];
                        $hora_fim = $row_operador['hora_fim_turno'];

                        echo "<option value=\"$id_operador\" data-hora-inicio=\"$hora_inicio\" data-hora-fim=\"$hora_fim\">$nome_operador</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hora_inicio_producao">Hora Inicio:</label>
                <input type="time" id="hora_inicio_producao" name="hora_inicio_producao" min="1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hora_fim_producao">Hora Fim:</label>
                <input type="time" id="hora_fim_producao" name="hora_fim_producao" min="1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="produto_producao">Produto:</label>
                <select id="produto_producao" name="produto_producao">
                    <option value="un">Unidade</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantidade_producao">Quantidade Produzida:</label>
                <input type="text" id="quantidade_producao" name="quantidade_producao" min="1">
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Cadastrar Produção</button>
        </form>
    </div>



    <script>
        // Obtém a referência do campo de data
        var campoData = document.getElementById("data_producao");
    
        // Obtém a data atual no formato 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        var dataAtual = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    
        // Define o valor do campo de data como a data atual
        campoData.value = dataAtual;
    </script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Quando o valor do operador_producao é alterado
            $("#operador_producao").change(function() {
                // Atualiza os campos com as horas do operador selecionado
                var horaInicio = $(this).find(':selected').data('hora-inicio');
                var horaFim = $(this).find(':selected').data('hora-fim');
                var teste = 3:00:00;
                
                $("#hora_inicio_producao").val(teste);
                $("#hora_fim_producao").val(horaFim);
            });
        });
    </script> 
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score -2):

Qual erro é exibido?

O que você quer é possível com ajax e PHP(veja abaixo um pseudo-código, não está completo mas é uma ótima base de por onde começar! Ressalto que também utilizei jQuery.)

Inclua o jQuery para que funcione corretamente:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```js
$('#SeuSelect').click(function () {
const data = this.value;
$.ajax({
                 url: 'pagina-handle-dados.php?data=' + data,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
                            //id do campo que você quer popular, neste caso é uma div(por isso usei .innerHTML)
                            txt = document.getElementById("myspan2").innerHTML = "SuaFrase: " + obj.definido_no_retorno;
                        });
                    }
                });
```

```html
pagina-handle-dados.php:
~~faça sua conexão com o banco de dados~~

$data = $_GET['data'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(id) AS definido_no_retorno FROM tabelaQualquer WHERE dados=$data");
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Esta resposta não é útil? É EXATAMENTE o código que uso em uma das minhas páginas que precisei popular campo X baseado em um select... Algumas coisas por aqui simplesmente não fazem sentido às vezes.